# Two Audio Files Merged in one file, and save in the disk

Tags: .net, audio, c#-4.0, audio-recording

I'm trying to develop a basic program for editing audio and I'm having the following problem. I would pick two songs - separate files, no matter the format - and joining them into one. In this case, do a merge of these two files. Where would a responsible and sound with the lowest and one with the loudest sound in the foreground.

Would still need to merge these two files, the final song to be saved to disk. Does anyone know help me, recommending any library could, code, or article?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex. And here's an [article](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2010/11/merging-mp3-files-with-naudio-in-c-and.html) on how to merge MP3 files with NAudio using C# and Python.

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2010/11/merging-mp3-files-with-naudio-in-c-and.html

Also check out this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/CSharpWAVClassAndMixing.aspx) about mixing WAV tracks in C# - once you have the final WAV file you can just encode it to MP3 if that's your format of choice.