# merging multiple mp3 files

Tags: c#, javascript, bash

I am looking for a way to automate the merging of any mp3 files found within a specified folder in windows. Is there any script that exists to accomplish this task? I am using a voice recording program that split up a file in 5 minute segments so i dont really care about any tag info being preserved. I only wish to have one big audio file with the whole recording opposed to 5-6 different chunks. Please let me know if this is possible

Thanks

EDIT: An additional requirement is that the folder with the mp3 files are structured so there are multiple mp3 files with prefix 009 that go together. then there are multiple mp3 files with prefix 010 that all should form one file. I need it to intelligently concatenate all 009 group of files and all 010 group of files for example

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I merge/join MP3 files with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160888/how-do-i-merge-join-mp3-files-with-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193454/two-audio-files-merged-in-one-file-and-save-in-the-disk

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697512/merging-multiple-mp3-files-overlayered-not-sequential-in-a-single-mp3-file-in

Answer (score -1):

here is a sample code how to merge any files including mp3 together consider you have files a, b, c and you want to merge it all to c one file.

```
      byte[] a = File.ReadAllBytes(txt_a_path.Text);
      byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(txt_b_path.Text);
      byte[] c = new byte[a.Length + b.Length];
      a.CopyTo(c, 0);
      b.CopyTo(c, a.Length);
      File.WriteAllBytes(txt_c_path.Text, c);
```