# How to merge mp3 files in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have list of mp3 files that I would like to merge them into one file. I downloaded files locally into isolated storage, but I have no idea how to merge them. google doesn't help either. I don't know if its possible in wp8. (2) If not possible what specific solution you could advice (I also have my files in web).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you require the files to be merged into the app, uploading a pre-merged mp3 filed would be a better solution

Comment: I have mp3 files, (1) I can download them all through my app and then merge them into one, How to do merging? (2) I have all files in web, I don't wanna download them, I just read them all and merge them into one and then download the one merged, How can I do online merging without having files in my app. Both are my solution and I am looking for merging.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's anything specific about WP8 that would change this. I found a thread that might help:

[merging multiple mp3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486177/merging-multiple-mp3-files)